# pam_exec.so not running command or logging anything

Tags: linux, pam

I have created a new `authselect` profile with

```
sudo authselect create-profile login-hooks --symlink-meta --symlink-nsswitch --symlink-dconf --base-on=sssd
```

Then I appended the following line to `/etc/authselect/custom/login-hooks/postlogin`

```
session     optional                   pam_exec.so log=/tmp/debug.log sh -c 'findmnt /var/home/$PAM_USER/host-man-files || mount --bind /usr/share/man /var/home/$PAM_USER/host-man-files'
```

Then I activated my new profile:

```
sudo authselect select -b custom/login-hooks with-silent-lastlog with-mdns4
```

And created the log file

```
touch /tmp/debug.log
```

Then I logged out and logged in again.

There is nothing in `/tmp/debug.log` and nothing relevant in `journalctl -xb` either, but the bind mount has not been created:

```
[greenrd@fedora greenrd]$ findmnt /var/home/greenrd/host-man-files
[greenrd@fedora greenrd]$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: The line I added is there in `/etc/pam.d/postlogin`, so it seems like `authselect` did its job correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I should not have created the log file in advance! It turns out that the Linux rule that other users cannot write to files you created in /tmp *even applies to root* - which was counterintuitive to me, since I thought that in terms of file permissions, root could do anything that ordinary users could do! Apparently not in this particular case!

Once I fixed that problem:

```
rm /tmp/debug.log
```

and started `sshd` for faster and more informative testing:

```
systemctl start sshd
```

I got further:

```
[greenrd@fedora greenrd]$ ssh localhost
greenrd@localhost's password: 
/bin/sh failed: exit code 2
Last login: Sun Jul  9 11:46:55 2023 from ::1
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ cat /tmp/debug.log 
*** Sun Jul  9 11:48:25 2023
/var/home/$PAM_USER/host-man-files: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
*** Sun Jul  9 11:48:33 2023
/var/home/$PAM_USER/host-man-files: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

I didn't understand that error message, so I decided to just create a script file containing my command line, and call that, instead of trying to inline the whole command line in the config file.

But that didn't work either - from `journalctl -xb`:

```
Jul 09 12:06:03 fedora sshd[60361]: pam_exec(sshd:session): execve(/var/home/greenrd/.local/bin/create-bind-mount,...) failed: Permission denied
```

The file is executable by all users:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ ls -l /var/home/greenrd/.local/bin/create-bind-mount
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 greenrd greenrd 120 Jul  9 12:00 /var/home/greenrd/.local/bin/create-bind-mount
```

so I guess some policy somewhere doesn't like me running files in that path from pam_exec?

Maybe it's SELinux?

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ sudo getenforce
Enforcing
```

OK, let's try to put SELinux in permissive mode and try again:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ sudo setenforce 0
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ 
logout
Connection to localhost closed.
[greenrd@fedora greenrd]$ ssh localhost
greenrd@localhost's password: 
Last login: Sun Jul  9 12:06:03 2023 from ::1
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ findmnt /var/home/greenrd/host-man-files
TARGET                           SOURCE                                                                                                                          FSTYPE OPTIONS
/var/home/greenrd/host-man-files /dev/xvda3[/root/ostree/deploy/default/deploy/b9990bf2421b057e99ca7df81d575c1ccedb6b4da571adba77142ded8ed5c778.0/usr/share/man] btrfs  ro,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v
```

Finally, it worked!

Comment: Drop your script into https://shellcheck.net. The message from PAM, "_host-man-files: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching [quote]_", is telling you there's a missing quote on the first line. This also suggests you are missing a `#!` as the first line

Comment: No, that error came from the time when it wasn't a script file, it was just an embedded command in `/etc/pam.d/postlogin`.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mind-reading wasn't up to knowing that. You quoted an error message and wrote, "_I didn't understand that error message_". How else was I supposed to interpret that other than as a call for help. Which I offered